# Spring boot: HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a `login.html` file located in `static/` directory, and I wrote a `@RestController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", produce = "application/json")
public String login() {
    // ... ...
}
```

I got `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` when access `/login.html`. Why Spring Boot don't return the static content `login.html`?

Comment: @RequestMapping annotation does not have property like "produce", I think you wrote it wrong in here.However, be sure that  you have jackson dependency in your pom.xml.
                <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning an HTML page, you would typically use `@Controller`.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Take a look at this Spring Guide for more information:

[Securing a Web Application](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)